# Javascript API fetch loop using offset

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm fetching data from an API that has a limit of 50 records per call.   There are 10,000 records in total that I need to retrieve so looking at using pagination via the offset parameter to achieve this.

I'm not too familiar with the syntax I need to use but I would like to keep looping through the fetch until the number of records returned for a single call is < 50 to signal the final page.

I need my JSON responses from each call to be appended together, in addition to a final 'count' that gives me 10,000

```
let offset = 0

       fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?collection=womenandweapons&format=json&offset=${offset}&limit=50&order_direction=desc`, 
      {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
        
      })
    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

      let len = Object.keys(data.assets).length
      console.log(len)
      console.log(data.assets)
    })
    
    
    offset += 50
```

Comment: `limit=${offset}&limit=50` should be something like `offset=${offset}&limit=50`.

Comment: If you use async/await (on the `fetch`) you can simply use a `for` or `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck doing something like this:

```
const main = async () => {
    const url = new URL(AIRTABLE_URL);
    let data = await fetcher(url, AIRTABLE_API_KEY);
    storiesTotal = mapData(data.records);

    while (data.offset) {
      data = await fetcher(url, AIRTABLE_API_KEY, data.offset);
      storiesTotal = [...storiesTotal, ...mapData(data.records)];
    }
  }

main();
```